# Xcode: Are all app icons necessary to publish?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

Looking at the AppIcon assets, I realized I needed multiple scaled icons for my app icon.

1. Do I need to fill up all of the necessary icons in order to publish the app? (for example, there is a iOS 5/6 section for icon sizes (57x57px and 114x114px) that I have no idea how to get)
2. Would it be possible to limit my app so that only users with iOS 7 and up could use it, and would that get rid of the section for iOS 5/6 icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few free and inexpensive apps that can easily produce a full set of icons. Recommendations really is a cause to close your question - I'd suggest you simply search via your favorite app engine (or in the MAS) on this, you'll find them.

Regards to question #2... you can easily limit the baseline OS version in Xcode, but that won't change what it thinks you need for an Appicon asset set. But the *real* question you should be asking for this is what does Apple (or *AppStoreConnect*) require?

[Here's what you need.](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/)

Scroll down a bit to "App icon Sizes". You'll see it currently is 2 iPhone, 2 iPad, and one for the App Store itself. Make it square - they round the corners. (Trust me, do not try to "frame" or "border" things - it can be done, but not without some work.)

But seriously, find an app - again, there are several - that simply takes that square icon (maybe 1024 x 1024) and simply generates the remaining ones that Xcode is looking for.